# Detect lists that start with same items as in another list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Given a `template_list`

```
template_list = [['item 1'], ['item 2','item 3']]
```

and a `test_list`, how can we identify if `test_list` starts with items that exist as sublist in the `template_list`?

For example:

```
template_list = [['item 1'], ['item 2','item 3']]
test_list = ['item 1']
print(any([x[:len(test_list)] == test_list for x in template_list]))
```

returns `True`, as expected

```
test_list = ['item 2', 'item 3']
print(any([x[:len(test_list)] == test_list for x in template_list]))
```

returns `True`, as expected

but I want the following 2 cases to return `True` too:

```
test_list = ['item 1', 'irrelevant item 1', 'irrelevant item 2', 'irrelevant item 3']
print(any([x[:len(test_list)] == test_list for x in template_list])) # returns False
```

```
test_list = ['item 2', 'item 3', 'irrelevant item 1', 'irrelevant item 2']
print(any([x[:len(test_list)] == test_list for x in template_list])) # returns False
```

So, what I **expect** is when `test_list` starts with exactly the same items as one of the sublists in `template_list`, even if there are more items in the `test_list`, to return `True`.

How can I achieve that? Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your logic to the following (to check if any entry of `template_list` is a starting part of `test_list`):

```
any(x == test_list[:len(x)] for x in template_list)
```